# Wasn't able to figure out why the value of integer changed, even while debugging my program?

Tags: c, arrays

code:-     to reverse the elements of array by swapping

compiler:- code blocks 13.12

whenever i tried to compile and run this code an unknown value appeared instead of that reversed array, after debugging i realized that code is working just fine upto that swapping section, the real  problem begins after that while printing the value of c instead of assigning as zero is automatically assigned into the value i put for n in the start of the program;

and so it prints out the value of arr[n] which has not been assigned by me, as it is a garbage value

i've compiled it online, same issue. please help me i'm very curious to figure out my fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
int n,c,t,end,arr[100];


//entering the number of elements
printf("enter the number of elements of array\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
end=n-1;


//printing the array
printf("enter your array\n");
for (c=0;c<n;c++)
    scanf("%d",&arr[c]);


//swapping the array's value
for (c=0;c<n/2;c++)
{  
     t=arr[c];
    arr[c]=arr[end];
    arr[end]=t;
    end--;
}


//printing the new array
printf("reversed array is\n");
for (c= 0;c<n;c++);      
/*at this point the value of c becomes equal to the n (i.e, the number of     
elements of the array)*/     
 printf("%d\n",arr[c]);


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `for` loop is terminated by `;` therefore `printf("%d\n",arr[c]);` is executed after the loop completes.

Comment: #findthesemicolonerror

Answer (score 1):

The last for loop has on its end ; 
Delete them

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reversed array, change the for statement loop ends ';' remove the semi colon in printing.

```
printf("reversed array is\n");
for (c= 0;c<n;c++)      
/*at this point the value of c becomes equal to the n (i.e, the number of     
elements of the array)*/     
 printf("%d\n",arr[c]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for (c= 0;c<n;c++);
```

by

```
for (c= 0;c<n;c++)
```

Acually your code

```
for (c= 0;c<n;c++);
  printf("%d\n",arr[c]);
```

is equivalent to

```
for (c= 0;c<n;c++)
{
}

printf("%d\n",arr[c]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
printf("reversed array is\n");
for (c= 0;c<n;c++);      <---------------- ERROR
  printf("%d\n",arr[c]);
```

You see, this semicolon makes the **for loop's body to be empty**.

So the code is equivalent to this:

```
printf("reversed array is\n");
for (c= 0;c<n;c++)
  ; // empty body
printf("%d\n",arr[c]); // c equals n
```

So, when you try to print your array, `c` has a value equal to `n`, thus you are going out of bounds, which leads to ***Undefined Behavior***.

Answer (score 0):

Your index counter c holds the last element of the array which is always '\0'. Arrays are basically pointer to the first element and the end is indicated by '\0' aka terminating character at the end. when you did `for(c = 0; c < n; c++);`c will increment and become equal to 'n'. I think I understand why you thought this should've retuned c = n-1 since you used c < n not c <= n however the whole condition will be executed up too c++ before its determined whether to execute the coming closure or not (In this case, it doesn't matter since the for loop does not have a closure). so the whole thing ends up giving c = n.

I hope this make it clear but just as an advice, try to put space between operators and practice best indentations while learning programming as it might be hard to get the habit once you're used to it.

Answer (score -1):

I think that yur mistake is this:

```
 for (c= 0;c<n;c++);
```

`n` is the number of elements (p.e. 5 elements), but your last element is in `arr[n-1]`.

Try with `for (c= 0;c<(n-1);c++);` or `printf("%d\n",arr[c-1]);`

Comment: `c<n` means that when `c==n` the for loop stops executing

Comment: @RNar I think that he wants show only the last elemento, not show all elements

Comment: I don't know, he said "the real problem begins AFTER that while"... not a while... ok... "printing the value of c". His problem is not this for.